# Minitest dynamically adding test cases with helper method in module

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am trying to dynamically define test cases using a helper method `add_snapshot_test` in a module called `SnapshotTest`.

I did some research on how to dynamically define test cases, and it looks like you define it inside class but outside methods, like this:

```
class ABCSnapshotTest < Minitest::Test
  include SnapshotTest

  #TODO: doesn't work
  add_snapshot_test('TX') do |filename|
    #...
  end
end
```

However, this fails with error `undefined method 'add_snapshot_test'`. I've tried putting it in `initialize` but not only did it not work, but I shouldn't override `Minitest::Test`'s constructor.

How can I make this work? Here's the `SnapshotTest` module definition:

```
module SnapshotTest
  def snapshot_dir
    @current_dir ||= File.dirname(__FILE__)
    @snapshot_dir ||= File.join(@current_dir, 'snapshots')
  end

  def add_snapshot_test(snapshot_filename, &block)
    define_method("test_#{snapshot_filename}") do
      # ...

      assert_equal(snapshot, output, "#{self.class.name} output doesn't match the snapshot")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: the `add_snapshot_test` is a instance method, but you called it in class. Replace `include  SnapshotTest` with `extend SnapshotTest` should work.

Comment: @Spikie Thank you! That defines the test case, but now I cannot access `snapshot_dir` in the same module from `add_snapshot_test`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

#### Class methods vs instance methods

It is different between instance methods and class methods in ruby. You can not call instance methods on class, and vice versa. When we call a method, ruby will find `self` in current scope, and find the method defintion from his ancestor chain.

```
class ABCSnapshotTest < Minitest::Test
  extend SnapshotTest

  # self is ABCSnapshotTest 
  add_snapshot_test('TX') do |filename|
    #...
  end
end
```

To call `add_snapshot_test` on `ABCSnapshotTest` class, we should `extend` not `include` `SnapshotTest` module. And we should modify `define_method`, because it is also defining instance methods.

```
module SnapshotTest
  def snapshot_dir
    @current_dir ||= File.dirname(__FILE__)
    @snapshot_dir ||= File.join(@current_dir, 'snapshots')
  end

  def add_snapshot_test(snapshot_filename, &block)
    class << self
      define_method("test_#{snapshot_filename}") do
        # ...

        assert_equal(snapshot, output, "#{self.class.name} output doesn't match the snapshot")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

or

```
singleton_class.instance_eval do
  define_method("test_#{snapshot_filename}") do
        # ...

     assert_equal(snapshot, output, "#{self.class.name} output doesn't match the snapshot")
  end
end
```